# PHP code from module for AJAX output fails to open file with require_once

Tags: php, database, drupal, jquery

I am writing a small Drupal module which is basically a lot of jQuery code. However it is AJAX code which takes it's input from a PHP script in the same module.

The PHP script needs to retrieve database information so I have the following in the PHP file:

```
require_once './includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);

print "respondiing just fine!";
```

My problem is I get the following error:

> **Warning**: 
>   require_once(./includes/cache.inc) [function.require-once]:
>   failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in
>   **/home/dir1/www/dir2/includes/bootstrap.inc**
>   on line **1111**
>  
>   **Fatal error**:  require_once()
>   [function.require]:
>   Failed opening required
>   './includes/cache.inc'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')
>   in
>   **/home/dir1/www/dir2/includes/bootstrap.inc**
>   on line **1111**

I have tried many directory traversal combinations with no success.

Comment: Is the path shown in the error message correct? Have you verified the file is actually there? Have you checked permissions on that directory?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
define("APP_PATH", dirname(__FILE__) . "/");

require_once APP_PATH . 'includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);

print "responding just fine!";
```

Comment: I copied, pasted and executed but it didn't work. Apologies for my inexperience but am I meant to adjust any part of your code?           FYI, my php script is inside my module under a directory labeled php

Comment: This does not work. You either need to copy your file into the top-level directory of drupal or use the menu router system. See also http://drupal.org/project/js